# extracting GPB descriptor from a proto file

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have a proto file defining some GPB (proto buffer) messages.
I want to implement a simple python script that go over the different messages and write to external file (lets say a JSON file) the basic information regarding each of the messages' fields (name, type, default value, etc..).
I searched on the WEB and found that once I get the GPB descriptor the rest should be relatively easy.
However, I have no idea how to get the descriptor itself.
Can someone help me here??
10x

Comment: `GPB` are you talking about Google Protocol Buffers? Can you provid an example of your input .proto file and what you want your output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

`protoc` has an option `--descriptor_set_out` which writes the descriptors as a `FileDescriptorSet` as described in [`descriptor.proto` from the Protobuf source code](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto).  See `protoc --help` for more info.

Alternatively, you might consider actually writing your script as a [code generator plugin](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/other).  In this case, you wouldn't be generating code, but just a JSON file (or whatever), but the mechanism is the same.